# Проверка на null перед GetValueOrDefault

Tags: c#

Linq, метод [`Sum` для nullable-типов](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3f64ed9c588d83c4):

```
public static int? Sum(this IEnumerable<int?> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    int sum = 0;
    checked {
        foreach (int? v in source) {
            if (v != null) sum += v.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

В чём смысл конструкции

```
if (v != null) sum += v.GetValueOrDefault();
```

насколько я понимаю, можно было бы без изменения результата написать просто

```
sum += v.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Так зачем же `if`?

Comment: Артефакт копипасты? В каком-то другом типе default может быть ненулевым?

Comment: Есть способ представления целых чисел в виде [кода со сдвигом](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Представление_целых_чисел:_прямой_код,_код_со_сдвигом,_дополнительный_код#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4_.D1.81.D0.BE_.D1.81.D0.B4.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.B3.D0.BE.D0.BC). Там default не будет равен 0. Только не понятно, имеет ли этот отношение к нашему примеру...

Comment: @АндрейNOP я сначала подумал, что для чисел с плавающей точкой могут быть нарушения точности, но руками потестил и такого не обнаружил.

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения именно результирующего значения действительно ничего не изменится, однако чем больше `null`-значений в представленном `source`, тем указанный метод будет работать быстрее.

Comment: Что-то не похоже на правду: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoOBmFAJiQGEcBvHJalAgSwDtgkBBAEzdQApHmwBjfgBokvAPxIAbmAA2ASio1K2GqtFMkAJwCmEJAF4kA/lhVrqdAGZIu0mUgCEhhgFcZ8xedU69AakN2AHQA4trAAGqyLtoA8poAItqWYG7AXHKmXigA7Fq6mTQAvjietOrM7GyEPBrGIuJSsgpm1MpZvHl6hsYF5j5I/o0yIWGRMtFxicmp6b1qcLk+c8XYhUA==

Comment: Непонятно, насколько выборка из памяти и сравнение дешевле, чем выборка из памяти и сложение.

Comment: Погонял эти же методы на другом компе и получил другой результат. wtf.

Comment: О, у вас есть бенчмарки? Давайте их в ответ! Может быть, у вас разные версии .NET на разных машинах?

Comment: Или может, вы случайно запустили Debug-версию или под отладчиком? Там результаты могут отличаться в разы.

Comment: Точняк, разные версии .NET, прогоню на другой и приложу в ответ!

Comment: @VladD результат, скорее всего, будет зависеть от содержимого коллекции и от % попаданий предсказателя переходов

Comment: @PashaPash: Мне всё же не верится без бенчмарков, что test + jmp настолько выгоднее, чем add. То есть да, тренированный предсказатель будет тянуть мимо сложения. А как составить хороший, репрезентативный бенчмарк?